# Android : how to set Default zoom lable of pdf inside webview?

Tags: android

Is there any way to increase the default zoom level of pdf showing in webview?

I am using the google docs url for open the pdf inside web view. it's open pdf file correctly but it's only zoom my file upto 100%. i want to zoom upto 200% like adobe reader.

Thanks in advance !